# Clarification regarding EclipseLink JPA properties

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink JPA version 2.6 and I wanted to use connection pool properties to set minimum and maximum connection in **persistence.xml** file. But I have two different set of properties as follows

```
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" /> 
  <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="64" />  
 <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="64" />
```

And

```
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="1" />
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.node2.min" value="16"/>
<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.node2.max" value="16"/>
```

I have doubt that which set I have to use in **persistence.xml** file. Anyone suggest me a best possible way for handling multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Partitioning) about partitioning your connection pool. If you not plan to partition your pool, the first settings-block is fine. Check the [Connection Pool settings](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm) for eclipselink.